# How to Remove selected item from listbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

i currently trying to view all the files and folder selected by the user in a listbox. At the Moment i am able to list what the user have chosen using the openfiledialogue HOWEVER i am now facing prob when i try to remove it form the listbox. i trying to allow the user to click on the checkbox beside the file and press the remove button to remove it

this is my code for remove button

```
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[i]);
        }

    }
```

this is the add file to listbox for reference jsut in case

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        // Display open file dialog
        openfiledialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        //openfiledialog.Multiselect = true;
        openfiledialog.Title = "Lock File";
        openfiledialog.Filter = "All Files | *.*";
        openfiledialog.ShowDialog();


        if (openfiledialog.FileName != "")
        {

        //move through FileInfo array and store in new array of fi
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string file in openfiledialog.FileNames)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(file);
            }        
        }

    }
```

and i pressed the remove button nothing happen and i saw some answer on google on the using of selectionmode but when i used that, my listbox does not have the property of selectionmode and have red lines underlined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `listView1.SelectedItems` use `listView1.CheckedItems` and change your `button2_click` to:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.CheckedItems)
                listView1.Items.Remove(i);

        }
```

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is because the `SelectedItems` property is actually a reference to `Items` collection and you change the collection while iterating through it.
try the following code

```
listView1.BeginUpdate();
ArrayList vSelectedItems = new ArrayList(listView1.SelectedItems);
foreach (string item in vSelectedItems)
{
   listView1.Items.Remove(item);
}
listView1.EndUpdate();
```

the `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods will optimize the performance of this action - the listView will not refresh itself during activities between these methods call.

Comment: FYI, using `ArrayList` is discouraged; the generic `List<T>` type is preferred.

Comment: @AdamRobinson How do you get `listView1.SelectedItems` into a `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           for(int i = 0 ; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i ++)
               listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[i]);

        }
```

Comment: I think this is completely wrong. OP's deleting code was fine - it properly deleted *all items*, just the wrong ones - selected and not the checked ones. your code however is worse - it will delete only part of all selected items (I guess half - assuming `Remove()` is stable/deterministic) because the `SelectedItems` will mutate after every `Remove()` call - its `Count` will be different, and item indexes will decrease by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Comment: please see the accepted answer. yours would not have resolved the issue here. besides OP's code from the question was doing the same thing as yours - only in reverse order.

Answer (score -2):

```
$x = @()

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "hello first"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {
        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox.SelectedItems)
            {$x += $objItem}
        $objForm.Close()
    }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,250)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(85,30)
$OKButton.Text = "Start Check"

$MoveRight = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MoveRight.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,80)
$MoveRight.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$MoveRight.Text = ">>"

$objForm.Controls.Add($MoveRight)


$MoveRight.Add_Click(
   {
        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox.SelectedItems)
            {[void] $objListbox2.Items.Add($objItem)}


            $selectedItems = $objListbox.SelectedItems;

if ($objListbox.SelectedIndex -ne -1)
{ 
    for ($i = $selectedItems.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--){$objListbox.Items.Remove($SelectedItems[$i])}
}
})

$MoveLeft = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MoveLeft.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,120)
$MoveLeft.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$MoveLeft.Text = "<<"

$objForm.Controls.Add($MoveLeft)

$MoveLeft.Add_Click(
   {

        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox2.SelectedItems)
            {[void] $objListbox.Items.Add($objItem)
        }


            $selectedItems = $objListbox2.SelectedItems;

if ($objListbox2.SelectedIndex -ne -1)
{ 
    for ($i = $selectedItems.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--){$objListbox2.Items.Remove($SelectedItems[$i])}
}

})

$Clearconsole = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Clearconsole.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(505,320)
$Clearconsole.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$Clearconsole.Text = "Clr console"

$objForm.Controls.Add($Clearconsole)

$Clearconsole.Add_Click(
   {
     $outputBox.Clear()

   })

$MoveAll = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MoveAll.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,160)
$MoveAll.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,20)
$MoveAll.Text = "ALL"

$objForm.Controls.Add($MoveAll)


$MoveAll.Add_Click(
   {
        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox.Items)
            {[void] $objListbox2.Items.Add($objItem)}


$objListbox.Items.Clear()
    $outputBox.text="test"
   })

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,320) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Console Window"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,350) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(565,200) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 

$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 

$objForm.Controls.Add($outputBox) 

$OKButton.Add_Click(
   {
        foreach ($objItem in $objListbox.SelectedItems)
            {$x += $objItem}
        $objForm.Close()
   })

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please make a selection from the list below:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox 
$objListbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,20) 

$objListbox.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"

[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("a")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("b")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("c")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("d")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("e")

$objListbox.Height = 200
$objListBox.Sorted = $True
$objForm.Controls.Add($objListbox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objListbox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox 
$objListbox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(315,40) 
$objListbox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,20) 

$objListbox2.SelectionMode = "MultiExtended"

$objListbox2.Height = 200
$objListBox2.Sorted = $True
$objForm.Controls.Add($objListbox2) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Comment: It would be good to have some explanation why this is the solution

Comment: The code does not seem to explain how to use it for the user's question. It is always recommended to add explanation before the code sample