# Removing an item from listbox in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am using VS2010, C#, .Net 4.0 and WinFormApplication.

I have a listbox which is populated from a datasource. I want to remove an item at a time when they are double clicked.

I read somewhere that if I populate my listbox from a datasource, no item can be removed. Is this true? If not, then how can I remove individual items?

I tried the following:

```
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedIndex);

listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedIndex);

lbTableColumns.Items.Remove(lbTableColumns.SelectedItem);
```

which cause the following error:

> ERROR: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Comment: Well you can remove it from the data source

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102681/how-to-remove-selected-item-from-listbox-c-sharp

Comment: listview and generic List<> are not same. @DimitarTsonev

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do I loop through items in a list box and then remove that item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380451/how-do-i-do-i-loop-through-items-in-a-list-box-and-then-remove-that-item)

Answer (score 0):

When using a `DataBinding` you cannot remove items from the `ListBox`, just as the error states. What would happen if the object changes within the `DataSource`, but has been removed from the presentation?

If you are working with DataSources you need to remove the object from the DataSource itself. Try something like this:

```
IList<MyObj> myList = new List<MyObj>();

private void DataBind()
{
    myListBox.BeginUpdate();
    myListBox.DataSource = myList;
    myListBox.EndUpdate();
}

private void OnMyListBoxItemDoubleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.RemoveAt(myListBox.SelectedIndex);
    DataBind();
}
```