# Remove an Item from the ListBox when user Clicks on it

Tags: c#, listbox

I just want to delete the item from the ListBox which the user clicks on it i am using:

```
   private void found_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        found.SelectedItems.Remove(found.SelectedItem);
    }
```

But it just shows a blink of selection and nothing else! Suppose i have a list as:

```
  word1
  word2
  word3
  word4
```

are in the listbox and when user clicks on word2 it should be deleted! I am new to c# can anybody give me any idea how to do it thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to remove it from the `DataSource` of your `ListBox` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102681/how-to-remove-selected-item-from-listbox-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
found.Items.Remove(found.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: I have tried it but was not working and now it starts working great job

Answer (score 1):

Because you removed it from `SelectedItems` (deleting the selection, not the item itself). You wanted to remove from `Items` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are storing the data source of your `ListBox` in a generic `List<string>`. when the user clicks on a item, remove it from the data source, and then do the following:-

```
    private void Item_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string item = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString() ; 
        list_name = list_name.Where(x=>
                                                   {
                                                      if(x != item)
                                                      return true ; 
                                                      else
                                                      return false ; 
                                                   }.ToList() ; 
       listBox.DataSource = null ; 
       listBox.DataSource = list_name;
       // listBox is the name of your `ListBox`.
        // list_name is your original list.
   }
```

EXPLANATION:-
First I store the value of 'Selected Item' say Word2 in a variable called as `item`.
Then I tranfer all the contents of previous list onto another  list using LINQ.
After that I change the `DataSource` of your `ListBox`, so that it gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( found.SelectedIndex <> -1 )
    found.Items.RemoveAt(found.SelectedIndex);
```